# How to use vbKeySpace in C#?

Tags: c#, vb6

I am using one VB function into my MVC project Business Object Class.

Sample Code in VB,

```
intUBound = Len(astrInValue);
For intLoop = 1 To intUBound
    strChar = Mid$(astrInValue, intLoop, 1)
    intCharASCII = Asc(strChar)

    If intCharASCII = vbKeySpace Then
        strEncodedStr = strEncodedStr & "+"
    Else
        strEncodedStr = strEncodedStr & strChar
    End If
Next intLoop
```

C# code like,

```
intUBound = Strings.Len(astrInValue);
for (intLoop = 1; intLoop==intUBound; intLoop+=1)
{
    strChar = Strings.Mid(astrInValue, intLoop, 1);
    intCharASCII = Strings.Asc(strChar);

    if(intCharASCII == vbKeySpace)
    {
        strEncodedStr = strEncodedStr + "+";
    }
    else
    {
        strEncodedStr = strEncodedStr + strChar;
    }
}
```

Here, how to use **vbKeySpace** in C#?

Comment: Don't translate a code from one language as it is. Instead rewrite it. Don't use `Strings.Len` `Strings.Mid` etc in c#, you'll be ruining a C# developers day by doing it. So, understand what that code does, and just write the logic in c#.

Comment: Since all you're doing in either version of the code is replacing space characters with a plus "+", why are you not just using the Replace function? C#: `astrInValue.Replace(" ", "+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vbKeySpace is just a constant integer value and you can just type 32 instead of vbKeySpace.

```
if(intCharASCII == 32)
  {
     strEncodedStr = strEncodedStr + "+";
  }
```

But like mentioned in the comments, it is advisable to avoid translating legacy code like this.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx